# PayPal Rest API complete the payment but not shown in sandbox transactions

Tags: paypal

I created a PHP script with PayPal Rest API. When I complete the payment the site redirect to the finish page with the label of the payment success, but when I go to the sandbox paypal site, I can't see any transactions. What I can do for solve this issue?

Here there are the 3 scripts:

**start.php**

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

define('SITE_URL', 'http://192.168.1.105/Fenix/Include/pay.php');

$paypal = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
    new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
        'AX5IC3G3s-XRzfMgmSUjEPGbHAjD6PL80skf7Xck50OKWXQ2nGf-9NWk5FjSaMCh1FPpxFvUioqZEbjy',
        'EJ8GDd08PwnRM1VxYzT2-fBmxAYzykYZ_zlwHi_zqmFGOQzaoXHAffM5DSiBDTcd8L6OpyDzGt5gtmMU'
        )
);
```

?>

**checkout.php**

```
<?php

include "./vendor/autoload.php";

use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;

require 'start.php';

/*
if (!isset($_POST['product'], $_POST['price'])){
    die();
}
*/

$product = "Fenix ID";
$price = 0.01;
$shipping = 0;
$total = $price+$shipping;

$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

$item = new Item();
$item->setName($product)
     ->setCurrency('EUR')
     ->setQuantity(1)
     ->setPrice($price);

$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList->setItems([$item]);

$details = new Details();
$details->setShipping($shipping)
        ->setSubtotal($price);

$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency('EUR')
        ->setTotal($total)
        ->setDetails($details);

$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
            ->setItemList($itemList)
            ->setDescription('Fenix ID')
            ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(SITE_URL . '/pay.php?success=true')
             ->setCancelUrl(SITE_URL . '/pay.php?success=false');

$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale')
        ->setPayer($payer)
        ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
        ->setTransactions([$transaction]);

try {
    $payment->create($paypal);
}catch (Exception $e){
    die($e);
}

$approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();
header("Location: {$approvalUrl}");
```

?>

**pay.php**

```
<?php

use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution;

require 'start.php';

if (!isset($_GET['success'], $_GET['paymentId'], $_GET['PayerID'])) {
    die();
}

if ((bool)$_GET['success'] === false) {
    die();
}

 $paymentId = $_GET['paymentId'];
$payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $paypal);
$execution = new PaymentExecution();
$execution->setPayerId($_GET['PayerID']);



echo "Payment success!";
```

?>

Thanks for the help.